# how to create custom template for a product type in drupal 8 commerce

Tags: 8, theming, commerce

I want to have separate twig templates for each product type in drupal 8 commerce to customize them.

is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

by default drupal 8 uses `commerce-product.html.twig`. you can find it from `modules/contrib/commerce/modules/product/templates/` and copy and paste it to your `template` folder in your theme.

and to create separate template file for each product type you can add `--product type` at the end of file name. for example if you have `shoes` product type then you should create a file `commerce-product--shoes.html.twig`.

then drupal uses the new template for shoes product type only.

Comment: @ali-hr How can i get list of all available variables? for e.g product.title, product.variations etc etc It will be easier to use if there is some kind of a list or cheat sheet.